# I have the following code for encryption and decryption. I manage to encrypt the string but can not decrypt it back

Tags: c#, rijndael

Here the code for encryption

Did I code it correctly? or I need to make a change? I am using visual studio 2013 and framework 4.5.

```
            cipherData = textBox_Plain_text.Text;
            plainbytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cipherData);
            plainKey = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("0123456789abcded");
            desObj.Key = plainKey;
            desObj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            desObj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, desObj.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(plainbytes, 0, plainbytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
            cipherbytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            textBox_Encrypted_text.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cipherbytes);
```

Here the code for decryption. After I try to decrypt it, only first letter show up

```
  System.IO.MemoryStream ms1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cipherbytes);
  CryptoStream cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms1, desObj.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            cs1.Read(cipherbytes, 0, cipherbytes.Length);
            plainbytes2 = ms1.ToArray();
            cs1.Close();
            ms1.Close();
            textBox_Decrypted_text.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainbytes2);
```

Here the result

[image]

Comment: This is your first problem: `textBox_Encrypted_text.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cipherbytes)`. The encrypted data *isn't* plain-text encoded with ASCII. To represent arbitrary binary data as text, you should use hex or base64. The latter is probably simplest: `textBox_Encrypted_text.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherbytes);`

Comment: You should also consider using some crypto library like Inferno. That should take away all these problems with converting stuff, choosing the right padding etc..

Comment: look at this may be it will be helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09d0kyb3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i'd already change to base64 but still cant get the result. Any solution perhaps?